# Linux - set new random password for user via script

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, change-password

I am writing a script in bash. part of it is to set a new random password for a user.
For now, I am generating random passwords with pwgen tool.
It looks like

```
    pwgen -s 13 10 | head -1 > pasChange.txt
    cat pasChange.txt: NOy3a8S53Jged
```

How can I set a random password as the user password? If you do have a different method I will be glad to hear.
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps look at the `chpasswd` command.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying! I did try to use it. I am not sure how to use it with a text file thou

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy solution for anyone who's interesting.

```
sudo apt-get install pwgen                    ## Install pgwen
pwgen -s 13 10 |head -1 > change_pas.txt      ## Insert random string into txt file  
yes `cat change_pas.txt` | sudo passwd pi     ## Change the password to the string in 
                                                 the txt file
```